# How to concat item to pipeline?

Tags: powershell

I have a regex scanning files and pulling some values out of them in a pipeline:

```
ls . -Include *.cs -Recurse | Select-String "LoadJsModule" |
   % { $_ -match 'LoadJsModule\("(\S+?)"'; } | ? { $_ } |
   % { $matches[1] } | % { do-Something $_ }
```

which gets something like

```
admin
invoices/app
warehouses/app
```

Let's say I notice that my regex pipeline is getting 90% of the things I want it to grab but missing a few special cases - a string "foo" and a string "bar". How can I add these properly to the pipeline so it contains

```
admin
invoices/app
warehouses/app
foo
bar
```

before I pass each to `do-Something`?

Note that I know I can run the above and *then* `do-Something foo` and `do-Something bar`. There's a dozen different ways to solve the concrete problem. I'm looking specifically to increase my understanding of the PowerShell pipeline so I'd like to know how to mix these values into it directly.

Comment: `&{command1;'foo';command2;'bar';command3}|%{do-Something $_}`

Comment: @PetSerAl I'm not sure I see how that fits with my above code? It looks like its probably right, but I'm just not seeing it - can you post a more flushed out solution as an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: My guess would be line 2 in the question.  `% { $_ -match 'LoadJsModule\("(\S+?)"'; -and 'foo' -and 'bar' } | ? { $_ } | %{$matches[1]}
`  See if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject the two strings via the `-End` parameter of [`ForEach-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849731.aspx):

> **-End<ScriptBlock>**
>   Specifies a script block that runs after processing all input objects.

```
ls . -Include *.cs -Recurse | Select-String "LoadJsModule" |
  % { $_ -match 'LoadJsModule\("(\S+?)"'; } | ? { $_ } |
  % -Process { $matches[1] } -End { 'foo', 'bar' } | % { do-Something $_ }
```

Note that using `Select-String` and `-match` is redundant. Since you're using the `$matches` collection later on I'd drop the `Select-String`. Also, I'd run `-match` in a `Where-Object` statement, not a `ForEach-Object`.

```
Get-ChildItem -Include *.cs -Recurse |
  Where-Object { $_ -match 'LoadJsModule\("(\S+?)"' } |
  ForEach-Object -Process { $matches[1] } -End { 'foo', 'bar' } |
  ForEach-Object { do-Something $_ }
```